# Offline React-Router Navigation for local bundle running through Android WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, android-webview

I'm currently having an issue setting up a working react-router navigation for a ReactJS app that is bundled and run through my Android app's WebView. The app needs to work offline, so I am currently loading the React app from the locally stored assets as:

```
file:///android_asset/build/index.html
```

It loads up the landing page fine but as the react-router setup I have depends on updating and matching url paths the Links and Routes that I currently have are not working with the local file path that WebView is using, clicking on the first Link element to the `/next/path` route results in:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A 
history state object with URL 'file:///next/path' cannot be 
created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 
'file:///android_asset/build/index.html
```

I've been going through the react-router docs attempting to get this sorted but am still somewhat at a loss.

What is the best way to get this offline non-url routing running, if at all?

My current react-router set up is as so:

`App />` component:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <RoutesComponent
        {props etc}
      />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

`Routes />` component:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/next/path"
    render={props => ( <DesiredNextComponent {...props} /> )}
  />
  <OtherRoutesBelowetc. />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem?

Comment: Hi, I did get it to work in the end yes. But it was a few years ago now so I'm not 100% on what the fix was. The only thing I remember was that it was solved by doing something like switching the type of `<Router>` component used. So, instead of `<BrowserRouter>` it was using `<MemoryRouter>` or `<NativeRouter>`